# Homework - $f(n)=n(n+1)$ - calculate $f^{-1}(\mathbb{N})$

Tags: functions

i have the following function:
$f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ , $f(n)=n(n+1)$

Calculate: $f^{-1}({1})$, $f^{-1}({2})$, $f^{-1}(\mathbb{{N}})$ (Natural numbers)

for the first one i got the empty set, for the second one I got the solution $\{-2,1\}$.

However for the last one I couldn't really find a solution.
If i put in an even number, the result is also even. If i put in an uneven number, I also get an even result. Therefore not every natural number is in the solution.

Where am I making a mistake here?

edit: can't really make it format right. my bad! but its supposed to be the set that contains all natural numbers, not only natural numbers

Comment: Hint:  For $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, can $n(n+1)$ be negative?

Comment: oh you're right. n(n+1) is positive for all integers except 0

Comment: And $-1{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think like this:
$$f^{-1}(\mathbb{N}) = \bigcup_{a\in\mathbb{N}} f^{-1}{(a)}$$

then:

- $f^{-1}(1)=\emptyset$
- $f^{-1}(2)=\{-2,1\}$
- $f^{-1}(3)=\emptyset$
- $f^{-1}(4)=\emptyset$
- $f^{-1}(5)=\emptyset$
- $f^{-1}(6)=\{-3,2\}$
- $f^{-1}(1)=\emptyset$
- $\vdots$
- $f^{-1}(12)=\{-4,3\}$
- $\vdots$

As you can see, most of the values will be empty, but numbers of the form $(n)(n+1)$ are non empty, and their values will give you the whole list of $\mathbb{Z}$ except for  $\{-1,0\}$.

Comment: Thanks! so basically the solution is the set of numbers that can be written in the form of n(n+1).

Comment: @23408924 No!, the solution is all $\mathbb{Z}$ except for $-1$ and $0$. Remember that you were asked by inverse map $f^{-1}$, so you need all the numbers $n$, for which $n(n+1)$ is a natural number

Comment: oh yeah you're right I misunderstood. I think i need to reread some stuff. thank you very much!

Comment: Small correction: here, $f^{-1}$ is not the inverse *map*, but the inverse image (or preimage). It makes a difference, since $f$ is not bijective and hence an inverse map does not exist. In particular, the preimage $f^{-1}$ expects sets as an argument, and not elements of $\mathbb Z$ (or $\mathbb N$).

Comment: @Marktmeister you are right, sorry for my vas english i will correct

Answer (score 0):

Make a plot of the function
$$f:\quad{\mathbb Z}\to{\mathbb Z}\qquad n\mapsto n(n+1)\ .$$
This plot consists of isolated points in the $(x,y)$-plane. Then determine the set $S\subset{\mathbb Z}$ of all $n\in{\mathbb Z}$ satisfying $f(n)\in{\mathbb N}$, i.e., $f(n)$ integer and $\geq1$.